# loop in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, while-loop

I have a table that I need to pull all the child client IDs when I enter the parent id. The code would keep running through till the clientid = the parentid.
in the table below if I entered parentid 01 the results would be clientid 01, 02, and 04.

if a loop is not the best way to do this, what is the best option?

| ClientID | ParentID | Client |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 01 | Client01 |
| 02 | 01 | Client02 |
| 03 | 100 | Client03 |
| 04 | 02 | Client04 |

```
DECLARE @Client varchar(20)
set @Client='1000'
WITH _RecursiveCTE AS
(
-- Base case
SELECT iClientID, iParentClientID, sClientCode
FROM tblClient
WHERE iClientID <> iParentClientID -- Prevents infinite recursion with 
your specific data model

UNION ALL

-- Recursive case
SELECT C.iClientID, C.iParentClientID, C.sClientCode
FROM _RecursiveCTE AS RC -- Notice the self-referenced CTE here creates 
the recursion
INNER JOIN tblClient AS C ON RC.iClientID = C.iParentClientID
)

SELECT iClientID, iParentClientID, sClientCode
FROM _RecursiveCTE
WHERE sClientCode = @Client

UNION ALL

-- Makes sure we don't miss out on the case we pre-filtered from the 
recursive CTE
SELECT iClientID, iParentClientID, sClientCode
FROM tblClient
WHERE iClientID = iParentClientID
AND sClientCode = @Client
```

Comment: SQL Server 2008 is formally end of life. That means it no longer receives any updates... **not even critical security patches**. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it. For smaller projects, you may be able to update to the Express Edition of a more recent release for free.

Comment: Also, the solution will involve a [Recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [Recursive CTEs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) are generally the way to go when solving tree-type / hierarchy problems. Loops are generally not a great tool in relational databases which are meant to solve problems relationally, with set-based solutions.

Example recursive CTE:

```
WITH _RecursiveCTE AS
(
    -- Base case
    SELECT ClientID, ParentID, ParentID AS OriginalParentID
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    
    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive case
    SELECT YC.ClientID, YC.ParentID, RC.OriginalParentID
    FROM _RecursiveCTE AS RC -- Notice the self-referenced CTE here creates the recursion
    INNER JOIN dbo.YourTable AS YC
        ON RC.ClientID = YC.ParentID
    WHERE RC.ClientID <> RC.ParentID -- Prevents infinite recursion with your data model
)

SELECT ClientID
FROM _RecursiveCTE
WHERE OriginalParentID = '01';
```

Comment: thank you, i was stuck in an infinite recursive. I added the where statement but I get 1 results back. I was trying different options when I seen your second post to add the where statement but I still get 1 results. I can manually see that there should be some more results

Comment: @user3818712 Yea I was afraid of that. Trying to think how to work around your data elegantly. Seems strange for a `ClientId` to be a parent of itself. I'll let you know if I come up with an update.

Comment: ok I have made some changes but still not getting the results I am looking for. I have added the code that I am using in my question.

Comment: @user3818712 Finally had a chance to test it myself and quickly figured out the issue. Sorry about that. You need to pass the top-level `ParentID` through every level of recursion so you can correctly filter on it at the end. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @user3818712 Great! Sorry for the back and forth, I just needed to sit down at a computer screen to get it right lol. Cheers!